# how do I export my saved places in google maps?

Tags: google-maps, export

I've been using Google Maps to save the places in town that I have to deliver newspapers to. I want to export that list of saved places to another application via a GPX file. How do I do that?

can i have it plan my route?

Also can I use Google Maps to route a navigation route to hit all of those saved places or to maybe navigate me to each place efficiently?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.